# Finding the power series of $f(x) = (x^2 - \sin(x^2))/x^6$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Suppose $f(x) = (x^2 - \sin(x^2))/x^6$
By using the Maclaurin series for $\sin x$ at $x = 0$,  it is asked to find the power series for $f$ at $x = 0$.
I understand how to obtain the Maclaurin series for $\sin(x)$ and how to find the Maclaurin series for $\sin(x^2)$ but I can't seem to progress any further than that. I can't think of any way to incorporate my other factors $(x^2,x^6)$ into the power series at $x = 0$.

$$\boxed{f(x)=\frac{x^2-\sin(x^2)}{x^6}}$$
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\dots(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
$$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\implies$$
$$\sin(x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(x^2)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\implies$$
$$\sin(x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Simply plug it into the given function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the well known series for sine:

$$\frac{x^2-\sin x^2}{x^6}=\frac{x^2-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2(2n+1)}}{(2n+1)!}}{x^6}=\frac1{x^6}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{2(2n+1)}}{(2n+1)!}=$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{4(n-1)}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Comment: what happened to x^2 ?? Is it always zero that's why you removed it?

Comment: @VaiosArgiropoulos  If you write out a couple terms of the sum, you'll see that the $x^2$ cancels.  That's why the lower limit of the sum was changed from $n=0$ to $n=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Begin with determining the Maclaurin series for the numerator: by substitution,
\begin{align}
x^2-\sin x^2&=x^2-\biggl(x^2-\frac{x^6}{3!}+\frac{x^{10}}{5!}-\frac{x^{14}}{7!}+\dotsm\biggr) \\
&= \frac{x^6}{3!}-\frac{x^{10}}{5!}+\frac{x^{14}}{7!}-\dotsm
\end{align}
There remains to find a general formula, and divide each term by $x^6$.